# Rails - avoid autosave in association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, build, associations

My models and its associations are:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  validates :commenter, :presence => true
end
```

**Case1:** Automatically *save* method is called when I tried below code.

```
@post = Post.find(3)
@comments = @post.comments
p @comments #=> []
p @comments.class #=> Array
if @comments.empty?
  3.times do
    @comments << @post.comments.build
 end
end
p @comments.first.errors #=>{:commenter=>["can't be blank"]}
```

**Case2:** if I manually initialize same empty array to the @comments, auto save is not calling. for instance,

```
p @comments #=> []
p @comments.class #=> Array
if @comments.empty?
  @comments = []
  p @comments #=> []
  3.times do
    @comments << @post.comments.build
  end
end
p @comments.first.errors #=>{}
```

What is the best solution to avoid auto save and please any one explain why the above code behave differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails extensively uses monkey-patching, so rails Array is not the same thing as pure Ruby array. (Compare output from `irb > [].methods` and `rails c > [].methods`

According to the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) `<<` method of `has_many` collection

> instantly fires update sql without waiting for the save or update call
>   on the parent object

So most likely Rails have an "observer" of the collection events, and fires validation when you try to add new object.

In second snippet you use pure array (not `has_many` collection), so the update action is not fired.

To avoid update action you don't need `<<` at all

```
@post = Post.find(3)
@comments = @post.comments
if @comments.empty?
  3.times do
    @post.comments.build
 end
end
p @comments.size
=> 3
```

Comment: @dimuch-: thanks for giving clear explanation and working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Autosave is defined in the Post model. Read [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html) about Autosave. If I understand your question correctly, then it should be enough to define `:autosave => false`.

Comment: thanks for reply @davidrac. I tried :autosave => false in association but no changes.

Comment: Can you share the new code? BTW, where are the code samples you shared running? This code: `@comments << @post.comments.build` has other problems in it, unrelated to autosave...

Comment: I have set autosave option as false in post model such as

    `class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :comments, :autosave => false
    end`